# Change Emacs syntax highlighting colors

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, colors, font-lock-mode

I'm running Emacs, editing files in C++ mode and PHP mode. I love syntax highlighting as a concept, but the default colors are a travesty. I can barely read some of them: way too dark. What is the easiest way to change their values? I can't seem to find anything about this on the web. I don't even mind changing the binary as I'm compiling my own Emacs. I just want to find the place where it says blue is #0000FF and change it to #AAAAFF for example.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I find it easiest to use [color-theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) for this sort of thing.

But if you don't want to do that, put the cursor over the offending text, and hit `M-x customize-face`. It should default to the face that the cursor is over.

See *[49.1.6 Customizing Specific Items](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specific-Customization.html)*.

Comment: A nice [color theme](https://github.com/bmarcot/color-theme-pomgranate-explosion).

Comment: Problem is, one of the colors I simply can't read (it's a dark blue that's practically invisible over the black background) is whatever text is being displayed when I type `M-x customize-face`!  (Also, the ColorTheme link appears to have an issue)

Comment: Well I tried to fix the link to one that worked, but when it gets followed from this page it *still* doesn't work!!!

Comment: If `M-x customize-face` defaults to `hl-line`, it is because of the highlight line that marks an active line. To get real face of "offending" text, do `M-x global-hl-line-mode` to temporarily disable highlight line.

Answer (score 26):

Two ways - you can install the package color-theme, which has lots of nice schemes to select and is easier to do it by hand. The by-hand looks like this (in your *.emacs* file)

```
(custom-set-faces
   custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
   If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
   Your init file should contain only one such instance.
   If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "lightyellow2" :foreground "gray20" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight bold :width normal :family "liberation mono"))))
  '(background "blue")
  '(font-lock-builtin-face ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "Turquoise"))))
  '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "MediumAquamarine"))))
  '(font-lock-constant-face ((((class color) (background dark)) (:bold t :foreground "DarkOrchid"))))
  '(font-lock-doc-string-face ((t (:foreground "green2"))))
  '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "SkyBlue"))))
  '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:bold t :foreground "CornflowerBlue"))))
  '(font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:italic nil :foreground "CornFlowerBlue"))))
  '(font-lock-reference-face ((t (:foreground "DodgerBlue"))))
  '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "LimeGreen"))))
```

...

etc. etc.

You can also type

```
`M-x customize-face RET`
```

which will give you all the customizations to set, ultimately end up in your *.emacs* file.

Answer (score 21):

Put the cursor on a face ("color") that you want to change. Hit <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd>. That will tell you which face(s) are present at that position, and it will let you click to customize it/them. Save your customizations.

Comment: I'm clueless about what I am supposed to enter in the customization screen.  For one thing, some of the important stuff is in a font color that I can't read (that's what I'm trying to fix in the first place!) and second, I don't see any obvious references to color or how to change them.

Comment: @Michael: If you can't read the text in Customize, then use it from an Emacs session that is virgin: start Emacs using `emacs -Q`. If you can read the text then you should be able to see checkboxes for the attributes currently used to define the face you are customizing. Click the link `Show all attributes` to show all attributes. Check or uncheck any of the attributes, as needed. When you check a box you see its current value. If attribute `Background` or `Foreground` is checked then you can use the `Choose` button next to the current value to choose a different color for that attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about color highlighting at all, or none of the previous answers work for you (or take too much time and effort to figure out), here is a very simple solution that will get rid of colors altogether.

Typing the following will get rid of colors:

`M-x global-font-lock-mode`

You can also do this as an interim step to allow you to actually see everything your screen to try any of the above answers. In my case, this was very useful because the color of certain key pieces of text which would allow me to change colors were themselves nearly invisible - for instance, the prompt of M-x.

If you want the change to be permanent, you can add this to your *.emacs* file:

`(setq-default global-font-lock-mode nil)`

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Emacs 24.1, you can use `M-x customize-themes` to select a colour theme.

Emacs comes with a dozen or so themes with varying brightness and colourfulness, so you'll most likely find something that mostly matches your preferences.

You can also find more colour themes installable through MELPA <del>at https://peach-melpa.org/</del> - no, that web site seems to be down. You can [search for "theme" at melpa.org](https://melpa.org/#/?q=theme), but it doesn't show any screenshots.